# Servidor com hora intermitente

Tags: php, servidor, datetime, time

Tenho um servidor PHP externo que tem gerado alguns problemas de hora, algumas vezes ele gera a hora correta (ex: gera 17:00 as 17:00) e outras vezes ele gera com duas horas a mais (ex: 19:00 as 17:00).

Já tentei entrar em contato com o suporte do servidor, eles dizem que não existe problemas, mas ao gravar dados com data de alteração vejo muitas das datas com esse problema. Pensei em utilizar um servidor externo com horário confiável ou alguma função do PHP, para tratar o erro tendo em vista que definitivamente o servidor não é confiável...

Comment: já tentou setar a localização? `date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provavelmente seu Banco de dados está com um timezone e o servidor com outro.

No MySQL você poderá configurar o fuso horário executando a seguinte query no terminal, em algum programa como o MySQL Workbench, ou até pelo código.

```
SET time_zone='America/Sao_Paulo';
-- ou
SET @@global.time_zone = '-3:00';
```

No PHP Adicione no início de seus código o seguinte:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo");
```